# Take average over list of values from another aggregate SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to do this:

Take the final value of an event.

Take the difference between the predicted values of the time of that event and the actual time of that event and count how many were within `x` minutes of the event.

Now, I know that `SUM(CASE WHEN event_time - last_event_time < x, THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` will get me the last bit, when grouped by the ID.

However I don't know how to do rge double aggregate. There doesn't seem to be a useful list operator in sql server that I've found yet.

UPDATE:
Sample data.

```
ID:      Estimate:   Actual:
X1XX     02:22:21    <null>    
X1XX     02:35:20    02:24:21
X1XX     02:20:18    02:24:21
X1XX     02:40:10    <null>
X2XX     03:15:00    <null>
X2XX     03:30:00    03:25:00
```

Expected Results (within 5 minute boundary):

```
X1XX: 2
X2XX: 1
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you here; what you're asking isn't completely clear.

Comment: What are the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution (when I started actually thinking)

```
SELECT tablea.id, SUM(CASE WHEN tablea.event_time - t.last_event_time < x, THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) from tablea INNER JOIN
(SELECT id, MAX(Actual) as last_event_time from tablea 
GROUP BY id) as t
ON tablea.id=t.id
GROUP BY tablea.id
```

Make the subquery to do one aggregate, join that to the  table you already have and then aggregate over the joined table.